# How to find the index of a value in an array in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, indexing

I was trying to get the indexes of values in an 3D array and the simplest way that I found was as follows:

```
import numpy as np

# b is a 3D array
# 9 and 16 are the values I want to find the index

values = [9, 16]

for idx, x in np.ndenumerate(b):
    if x in values:
        print(f'idx: {idx}  x: {x}')
```

I hope I've helped someone out there :)

Comment: Please clarify the **question** you are asking. Otherwise, it may be to your benefit to create a question asking about this topic, and then answering your own question.

Comment: It's not a question! This is the solution! :)

Comment: If you think it is a good solution, then I advise re-reading the rest of my previous comment. As it stands (Exactly as you stated): "It's not a question!".  I would recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and checking out the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to better understand how Stack Overflow operates. If you truly think your content here is helpful and don't want it to be deleted, it should probably be restructured to frame a question that can then be answered by you, in the answer section. Otherwise your "question" will probably be removed by moderators.

Comment: Here is another resource to check out: [Can Stack Overflow users post examples instead of questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74411/can-stack-overflow-users-post-examples-instead-of-questions/74414); as well as: [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Comment: Oh! I am new here, thanks for your tips! I'll do that! :)